# How to create a function that returns a new stack?

Tags: c++

I'm doing my homework, I've created a stack by myself and want a function that create a new stack from a previous one that contains (e.g) only positive numbers.

I have done a void function that modifies the original stack and I can't keep it unmodified.
The code is organised:

- cell.h that contains in the private section element and pointers to next cell, constructor-destructor and getters-setters.
- stack.h that contains virtual pure methods (createStack()-emptyStack()-top().. )
- stackp.h derived class of stack.h that redefine every method in stack.h and contains printPositiveStack().

  ```
  template <class T>
  void stackp<T>::printPositiveStack(){
         stackp<T> auxp;
  while(!this->emptyStack()){
  int temp = this->top();
  if(temp <= 0){
      this->pop();
  } else {
      auxp.push(temp);
      this->pop();
  }
  }

  while(!auxp.emptyStack()){
  this->push(auxp.top());
  auxp.pop();
  }
    }
  ```

How can I create a function that returns a new stack without changing the original stack? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to do X without modifiying Y then make a copy of Y and apply X to the copy. Your question is rather unclear. I dont understand how the code relates to the question you are asking. You should post a [mcve]

Comment: I have a feeling he has no way to make a copy too, it's a totally locked down object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you cant iterate over the raw data and are only able to see/pop the last inserted element. Given this assumption, I think your only chance is a algorithm with a farily bad performance:

- Given you have Stack A
- Create Stack B by top()'ing and pop()'ing the current Stack you which to copy and insert the elements in Stack B (it will be a reversal of your current Stack A)
- Now do the same again, top()'ing and pop()'ing from Stack B, but now you copy the elements.

  - One for your current Stack A, so it will be the same as before
  - And one into your copy Stack C which you will then return

Comment: Thanks! I have modified the function! Now it creates a new stack with only positive elements and the original stack is immutate.

   template<class T>
   void stackp<T>::printPosStack(stackp<T>& p1, stackp<T>& p2, int k){ ... }


I used 'k' to delete elements greater than k, in my case 0 but I can use it in future to delete elements greater than another value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate a stack using only its public interface, there is only one way to do it, which is unstack it (top-to-bottom), saving all the elements you see, then restacking onto both the new stack and the original one. Something like this:

```
std::vector<T> elements;
while(!originalStack.empty()) {
  elements.push_front(originalStack.pop());
}

for(T& element : elements) {
  // Note: be careful about using references here, depending on whether the stack
  // makes a copy of the elements (like vector does).
  originalStack.push(element);
  newStack.push(element);
}
```

If your function is a member of the stack class, e.g. a copy constructor, you may be able to (and probably should) do something more efficient by using the internals. How that would look depends on how you have implemented it, and you have not shown that code. But just as an example, suppose that your stack internally uses a vector to store the elements on the stack, your copy constructor could look a simple as this:

```
StackP<T>(const StackP<T>& other) 
  : elements(other.elements)
{
}
```

Comment: is it really legal to use `this->` in the initializer list? Never seen that before

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Seems to me like it would be the only way to set a member that was hidden by a parameter with the same name

Comment: @Tharwen no, it definitely is fine to write `Foo(int value) : value(value) {}`. I cant point you to the relevant quote in the standard, though if you think about it there is no ambiguity, in **value** (value), the **value** can only refer to the member and for value you get shadowing like usual

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Ah right, I didn't think of that

Comment: Oops @formerlyknownas_463035818, I moved that line from the body to the initializer list.